# Create propertybag doesn't work the first time

Tags: property-bag

I have the following code below. The first time I run this code it doesnt create the property in the propertybag. The second time it will create the property. Why???

```
string newValue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(members);
            string currentValue = web.AllProperties[propertyName] as string;

            if (!newValue.Equals(currentValue))
            {
                web.AllProperties[propertyName] = newValue;
                needsUpdate = true;
            }

            if (!web.IndexedPropertyKeys.Contains(propertyName))
            {
                web.IndexedPropertyKeys.Add(propertyName);
                needsUpdate = true;
            }

            if (needsUpdate)
            {
                web.Update();
            }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
if (!web.IndexedPropertyKeys.Contains(propertyName))
            {
                web.IndexedPropertyKeys.Add(propertyName);
                needsUpdate = true;
            }

if (!newValue.Equals(currentValue))
            {
                web.AllProperties[propertyName] = newValue;
                needsUpdate = true;
            }

            if (needsUpdate)
            {
                web.Update();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the property before you update it. It is creating the property in the first run and updating the value in the second run.

Comment: see my update. Like this?

Comment: Yes, is it working?